# How do I make a level system in discord.py, or just any proper rpg level system?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, discord.py

How do I make a leveling system in discord.py? I'm currently using a database to store info on users. However, I want to make a endless/infinite leveling system. Which means when they pass the first level, the amount of xp points they have to gain to reach the next level multiplies.
For example:

A new user comes in. They start at level 1, this is their current xp level. Stats: Level 1, 1/20 xp points

Once they get past 20 xp points, I want their level to be level 2 and to get to level three, they have to get 40 xp. So the checkpoint/mark to get to the next level multiplies. Current Stats for New User: Level 2, 1/40 xp
Once they reach level 3, Stats: Level 3, 1/80 xp

And then I just want it to be an endless cycle. Just keep updating their level and multiplying their xp level mark by 2.

I'm using a mysql database. I already have 2 functions to update and show their levels. I just need to find out how to loop things. I'm not very familiar with loops.

I want their leveling system to be based on on_message events. Which means with each message, they gain one experience point.

This is my current on_message code:

```
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author
    guild = message.guild
    xp_update(1, member.id)
    print(f"{member} from guild {guild} said>> '{message.content}'")
    get_xp_stats(member.id)
    get_lvl_stats(member.id)
    if int(xp_results) == range(1, 49):
        lvl_update(1, member.id)
        await message.send(f"{member} has leveled up to {lvlresult}!")
    elif int(xp_results) == range(50, 99):
        lvl_update(1, member.id)
        await message.send(f"{member} has leveled up to {lvlresult}!")
    elif int(xp_results) == range(100, 199):
        lvl_update(1, member.id)
        await message.send(f"{member} has leveled up to {lvlresult}!")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Thanks a lot stackoverflow, hope you can help me.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you have so far? Couldn't you handle the level up in `on_message` as well since people can only gain XP by sending messages?

Comment: @Benjin I've included some code that should explain your question. I apologize for the inconvenience

Comment: You need to supply some more code, the functions used in the code you've provided would be nice, also I assume you have it properly tabbed? It's not here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT :**

Thank you to everyone for trying and thank you for participating. I've figured out the answer. I simply just had to modify some things. This is my full code.
It's honestly simple maths and algebra. I should take more math tuition, haha

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    member = message.author
    guild = message.guild
    get_max_lvl_stats(member.id)
    print(f"{member} from guild {guild} said>> '{message.content}'")
    get_xp_stats(member.id)
    get_lvl_stats(member.id)
    if xp_results > maxlvlresult:
        max_lvl_update(2, member.id)
        lvl_update(1, member.id)
    elif xp_results < maxlvlresult:
        xp_update(1, member.id)
    elif xp_results == 0:
        pass
    elif xp_results == maxlvlresult:
        xp_update(1, member.id)
    else:
        print("An error occurred with on_message lvl updating.")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```